# Display Database values using QR code in PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently new with PHP and the problem I have is that, I've research through youtube and google about examples of displaying database values by scanning the qr code. I for one hand is not familiar with any qr code in PHP. Is there a way do display (e.g. name, lastname and username by scanning the "id no") the values? Your reply is appreciated.

(I hope the people here aren't too hard and I'm willing to correct my question if there are any errors with it)

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to narrow it down. What data do you want to store in the QR code? How will you read it out? What are you using to generate the QR code? You should check out the [pages on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: on google, if i type `php qr code` top hits are libraries for qr code readers and generators. go do it, try something, and if you have a specific problem come back here.

Comment: @Machativity The data I wanted to store is the "id no" and when scanned , it will display the database values. I'm currently using the php qrcode from sourceforge last 2010 (kind of outdated tbh.) So my specific problem, are there any insights or examples on to how to display database values by "scanning" the "id no"? Thanks you very much for the replies. :)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Thank you for your reply, I have did that and got the idea on how to generate it. The problem is that, how do I generate it along side the "id no", have it stored in the database (mySQL) and display it along with my database values such as (name, lastname and username) on unto my search panel. Apologies if I can't relay my problem very well.